# Using Constructor for default member value

Tags: c++

In C++11, can do this to initialize an object without using initialization list:

```
 class Z{
   int a=0;
   int b;
   z():b(0){} //<-- a already initialized
   };
```

What I'm wondering is for class types, which of these is preferable:

```
 class Z{
   std::vector<int>a=std::vector<int>();
   //or instead:
   std::vector<int>a();
   int b;
   z():b(0){} //<-- a already initialized
   };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly default initialize `a`, since it will be default constructed. This will do fine:

```
class Z
{
  std::vector<int> a;
  int b = 0;
  z() {} //<-- a, b already initialized
};
```

Note that your second variant is a function declaration, not an initialization:

```
// function a(), returns std::vector<int>
std::vector<int> a();
```

so what you should have used is

```
// data member a is an std::vector<int>. Default construct it.
std::vector<int> a{};
```

Of course, if you do not want default construction, then this initialization at the point of declaration is very handy:

```
std::vector<int> a{0,1,2,3};
```

Comment: Well, I'm going for the general rule that you must initialize everything, and thus generally always use the initializer list for everything (as suggested by Scott Meyers) but in this case using the C++11 initializer ability instead.

Comment: Did Meyers really suggest explicitly initialising members that have perfectly good default constructors? That seems like rather odd advice. Are you sure you're not thinking of the advice to initialise things in the initialiser list (or the declaration, these days) rather than assigning them in the constructor body?

Comment: @Fellowshee Having a class such as `std::vector`be default-constructed doesn't mean it is uninitialized. If a type has a default constructor which sets up a valid state, letting that one be called implicitly seems to me like the clearest option.

Comment: @MikeSeymour actually he said specifically "The rule there is simple: make sure that all constructors initialize everything in the object." But this was before C++11 I think when the syntax described in this question became available.

Comment: I think the Meyers advice concerns putting all member variables in initizalization list: Z():a(),b(0) {} instead of Z(): b(0) without any mention of a.

Comment: @MikeSeymour He goes on to say: "Similarly, you can use the member initialization list even when you want to default-construct a data member; just specify nothing as an initialization argument. "

Comment: @Fellowshee it is a matter of interpretation. I know that user defined types' default constructor gets called, and I know `std::vector` has a sensible default construction, so I am already sure the constructor initialized the vector data member in my class.

Comment: @MikeSeymour and turning the page, he specifically recommends using the member initializer list for default constructed objects even though many programmers consider it overkill.

Comment: @Fellowshee but the point to take home is that `vector<int> a()` is a function declaration, and `vector<int> a{}` does what you want.

Comment: Thanks; can I assume that `std::vector<int>a` will do exactly the same thing as `vector<int> a{}` ?

Comment: @Fellowshee yes, absolutely.

Comment: If Scott Meyers really meant to say "Put everything in an initialization list," then I strongly disagree.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to do this:

```
class Z{
   std::vector<int> a;
   int b = 0;
```

};

This is the shortest version and also the easiest to read. It doesn't add any useless clutter and makes it quite obvious that you're default-constructor `a` and initializing `b` to `0`.